# Run Query against multiple namespaces with Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Is there any way in which using Spring Data a query can be executed on all keyspaces in Cassandra?

Comment: Could you share in detail what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: The main idea is that i want to have some sort of a mechanism that enables me to do a query(select, insert, update, delete) only on some keyspaces that i choose and by reading the documentation i can't seem to be able to do that so this is why i'm asking for help here. Atm i use the `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository` alongside with `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository` and this mechanism dosen't allow me to achieve the level of flexibility that i want.

Comment: Should i go with multiple sessions(only here i can set the keyspace on a single session) and manage that in my Java code? An approach like this seems very cumbersome for a db like Cassandra that promises lots of flexibility. So given query A and a set of keyspaces(K1, K2, K3, K4, K5 etc.), i would like the query A to be executed only on K1 and K4.

Comment: Can i achieve this somehow by using the APIs from Sping Data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer:

1. When using Spring Data Cassandra 1.x, you are need to setup individual `CassandraTemplate` instances for each keyspace you want to use.
2. With Spring Data Cassandra 2.x, we introduced the [`SessionFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/SessionFactory.java) interface to control which `Session` to use. We ship with [routing `SessionFactory` support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/session/lookup/AbstractRoutingSessionFactory.java) so you can provide multiple sessions and a discriminator (usually something `ThreadLocal`-based) to select the appropriate `Session`.

Some example code for 2.0 would look like:

```
class MyRoutingSessionFactory extends AbstractRoutingSessionFactory {

    ThreadLocal<String> lookupKey = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "default-session");

    void setLookupKey(String lookupKey) {
        this.lookupKey.set(lookupKey);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return lookupKey.get();
    }
}

class MyConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        MyRoutingSessionFactory factory = new MyRoutingSessionFactory();
        factory.setDefaultTargetSessionFactory(getRequiredSession());

        MapSessionFactoryLookup lookup = new MapSessionFactoryLookup();

        Session myOtherSession = …;

        lookup.addSessionFactory("default-session", getRequiredSession());          
        lookup.addSessionFactory("my-other-session", myOtherSession);

        factory.setSessionFactoryLookup(lookup);

        return factory;
    }

    // …
}
```

Comment: i have seen something similar in the documentation(in the last week this is what i was doing), but the code above still gets me to the same problem: i need to manage the sessions separately that come from the session factory(each session with its own keyspace) in order to achieve **given query A and a set of keyspaces(K1, K2, K3, K4, K5 etc.), i would like the query A to be executed only on K1 and K4**

Comment: so the code above helps me to have session S1 with keyspace K1 and session S4 with keyspace K4 and use both seesions to send the same query Q to them in order to update K1 and K4. A much needed configuration of the session object would be `Session s = new Session(K1, K4); s.execute(Q);` but it seems that this is not possible, at least for the moment.

Comment: It's not possible to run a single query concurrently/serial on multiple keyspaces with a single `execute(…)`/`insert(…)` call. Each query produces an own result (in the form of a`ResultSet`/`Exception`) but the methods return only a single response.