# Configure spring Cassandra with multiple keyspace

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to create multiple spring Cassandra sessions in my spring boot application

- One session connecting to primary Keysapce as configured in `spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name`
- One session connecting to `keyspaceB`

Configuration

```
@Configuration
// all the sessions have spring Cassandra configuration except keyspace
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String primaryKeysapce;

    @Value("${item.keysapce.b:keyspaceB}")
    private String keyspaceB;


    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return super.session();
    }

    @Bean("cassandraOperations")
    @Primary
    public CassandraOperations cassandraOperations() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject(), cassandraConverter());
    }

    @Bean("sessionB")
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean sessionB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = super.session();
        session.setKeyspaceName(keyspaceB);
        return session;
    }

    @Bean("cassandraOperationsB")
    public CassandraOperations cassandraOperationsB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new CassandraTemplate(sessionB().getObject(), cassandraConverter());
    }


    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return primaryKeysapce;
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name = primary_keysapce
spring.data.cassandra.username = xyz
spring.data.cassandra.password = abcd
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=myhost.company.com
```

In My code,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Resource(name = "cassandraOperationsB")
    CassandraOperations cassandraOperationsB;

    // hall point to primary one as per spring properties
    @Autowired
    CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Though it works as expected with keyspaces in localhost.

But this is not working as expected. It is not taking spring cassandra properties in application.properties. It is always pointing to default properties.

I am tring to connect to cassandra on myhost.company.com, but my application is connecting to localhost all the time.

Can some one help me whats wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Query against multiple namespaces with Spring Data Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933154/run-query-against-multiple-namespaces-with-spring-data-cassandra)

Comment: I would refer you to an good blog post on how to do it. In particular, you must use naming conventions and inheritance to specify which keyspace is used.
https://lankydanblog.com/2017/10/22/separate-keyspaces-with-spring-data-cassandra/